# How do I solve level 16 on Advanced difficulty?

Tags: dr-laser

I have been playing the Dr. Laser game for a while and have been stuck on level 16 of the advanced section for DAYS.

Can anyone possibly provide a hint?

Comment: The reputation in these two users is almost perfect

Answer (score 1):

Top left box only activates highest sensor. Also laser leaves box through bottom right tee.  Do not use straight pipes in top left box.   Please let me know how you do